# Revised list of close reasons: a proposal

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I propose the following revised list of close reasons:

- Duplicate
- Belongs on another site
- Unclear
- Almost entirely opinion-based
- Trivial

The goal is to streamline, simplify and flatten the list of close reasons, to promote them being used more correctly and effectively, and thereby sharpen the closure process.

In more detail:

1. **Leave "duplicate" as is.**
2. **Merge the three "belongs on another site" off-topic sub-reasons into one.**
3. **Retain "unclear"**. However, merge "request for debugging with no MVCE" into it.
4. **Retain "opinion-based"**. But emphasize the "almost entirely" part.
5. **Introduce a new "trivial" reason.** A meaningful proportion of questions cluttering the JS tag in which I work are at heart "trivial". Right now, there is no good reason for closing them. As I understand the history, the "trivial"-like reason was abandoned because it was being misused to close too many questions, among other reasons. But actually the removal of the "trivial" reason has had only two effects: first, determined close-voters close the question anyway with some other unrelated reason; and second, it is harder to close questions that should be closed.
6. **Remove "too broad"**. This close reason is itself, ironically, too broad. It is is a magnet for people looking for any old reason to close something, and also can result in interesting questions with potentially interesting answers being closed.
7. **Remove "recommend or find an off-site resource".**  As developers in this day and age, we spend more time finding and integrating with third-party libraries and tools than we do programming. Yet SO refuses to permit itself to become a useful repository of Q&A about how to find those libraries and tools.

An example of the associated verbiage for this new, flat set of reasons would be:

- **duplicate of**

  This question has been asked before and already has an answer.
- **belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network**

  Questions about general computing hardware and software, and professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration, are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User or Server Fault.
- **unclear what you're asking**

  Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. If your question is requesting debugging help ("why isn't this code working?"), such additional details must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, and the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.
- **almost entirely opinion-based**

  Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be **almost entirely** based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.
- **trivial**

  This question can be easily answered by consulting documentation, intros, tutorials, or other internet resources. Or, it was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced, or a simple typographical or logical error. Such questions are unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: We *did* have a too-narrow reason. It was abused and misunderstood more than it was used correctly. If you are proposing a 'trivial' close reason, then that's not going to happen. It has been proposed before.

Comment: If you want to write/publish tutorials, then there are *lots* of places on the internet where you can do that, SO simply isn't one of them, and doesn't *need* to be one of them.  Alternatively, if there is some specific piece of information that you think of when reading a question that's Too Broad then you can simply write a *specific* question that's actually on topic to which you can then answer, rather than just providing a woefully incomplete answer to a very broad question.

Comment: Now, community moderation involves humans, and is therefor not perfect. It can never be. It still takes 5 voters to actually close something, so it is not as if closure was instant, and moreover, *you* are part of the community and can vote to reopen too. *On the whole* I see little evidence that *Too Broad* is abused more than it is applied correctly.

Comment: As for the 'off topic' hierarchy: those reasons are configurable *per site*. The ones on Stack Overflow are specific to SO, other Stack Exchange sites use their own. So you can take your experience with the SO top-level reasons over to another site in the network, and know that the drilldown to Off-topic will be new and tailored to the topic of that specific site.

Comment: The first question linked in this post was not closed as too broad, as stated, but as "unclear". I didn't read the rest, because that shows the premise is just wrong...

Comment: It seems to have been closed as unclear by a moderator. Why would something like that happen?

Comment: @Kevin In any case, using as example of the "too broad" close reason being supposedly abused, a question closed as unclear, and then building an argument out of it is not very convincing....

Comment: I think this is an important conversation to have, I just wish it were framed better so that we could have a discussion about it. Close reasons have a major impact on both the type of questions asked as well as the overall sentiment of the site. The suggestion at the end should be posted instead as an answer with more details as to what the explanations would be for your proposed new reasons, and the bias should be removed so we can discuss close reasons in general as opposed to the bullet points at the end which greatly lack detail.

Comment: @Tunaki My apologies for the error, I've omitted that mention from the post. However, I suggest you read up on basic logical fallacies, including the fallacy that goes "since you made one mistake in your argument, therefore everything you said is doubtful". In any case, I did not "build the argument" out of that one case. I see cases of incorrect use of the too broad reason each and every day. To put it other way, the "too broad" reason is "too broad" to be useful. If people really want to keep "too broad" then fine, it does not affect the rest of the proposal anyway.

Comment: I find most of the questions I end up answering using the filter `[javascript] too broad` in the close vote queue. I can definitely attest to the widespread misuse of "Too Broad" in at least the JavaScript tag. I have spoken against its misuse (specifically in the JavaScript tag) repeatedly. I don't think the reason should be removed, but there is **definitely** a problem.

Comment: Relevant post if you want to mine close statistics: [2016: a year in closing](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/289797)

Comment: I also think there is a major difference between "A book could be written on the topic" and "A book would be required to answer the question".

Comment: Why would we want/need to get rid of (e.g.) the typo reason just because you could arguably fold it into another reason? What's wrong with a bit of granularity? I agree with TravisJ, this is a good conversation but personally I think your conclusions have taken much too much of a leap from the original problem

Comment: I really wish the last bit was a tl;dr at the top

Comment: @MartijnPieters To me it's of no value at all to have the same close reason structure on other sites. I don't need to "take my experience with the SO top-level reason" to another site", like Japanese. I would prefer each site to have a well-structured set of close reasons tailored to the site, not some all-size-fits-all top-level with site-specific reasons buried down within a list of sub-reasons.

Comment: Legitimate use cases of "too broad" include "requires a whole book to be answered" (as well put by @TinyGiant), "requires writing several hundred lines of code", and "asks a dozen questions in a single post". I entirely agree with your third paragraph, but eliminating "too broad" outright because of that would probably be an overreaction.

Comment: (For other people reading this: in my comment above, "third paragraph" refers to the third paragraph of the original revision of this question. In particular, one of its key points was that "[simply] because a book could be written about some topic does not mean that useful information could not be provided in a Stack Overflow answer format".)

Answer (score 14):

I don't think that removing the "recommend or find an off-site resource" is a good idea.

Yes, modern development requires finding many libraries and frameworks, but that doesn't make a Question and Answer site the best place to find them.

The stated reason for why that close reason was added still rings true today:

> they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

And the advice continues to be good:

> Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

If you can't do that, and are only looking for recommendations for a "good library that does X and Y", that could be closed using the "primarily opinion-based" close reason as well, since recommendations are pretty inherently opinionated. Sure, there are (very few) questions which actually call for expertise, but finding the best library that lets me pad a number with zeroes hardly seems one of them...

Finally, I find it fascinating how many people lack the skill (and the desire to obtain the skill) of searching the internet. In this day and age, it seems that skill would be even more important to procure and constantly improve. Just asking a bunch of other people to do it for you seems like a poor method of doing that.

Comment: Just the other day I flagged a rec request that had gotten 3 answers, at least two of which where promoting a product by the company in the user's profile.

Comment: @BSMP And then also flagged those answers as spam.

Comment: @Servy for it to be spam it must be unsolicited. If the question is asking for it, it is explicitly solicited. If the question is the problem, focus on the question. Doing so makes all other points moot

Comment: Hmm, I am failing to see the problem in recommending VS code as an IDE just because the answerer works for Microsoft, assuming recommendation questions are not considered off-topic in the first place. I think there is also a subtle (?) difference between "promoting" and "mentioning". Saying "VS Code is definitely the best IDE out there" is "promoting". Saying "VS Code is a well-regarded IDE" is "mentioning".

Comment: @TinyGiant Not disclosing affiliation makes it spam regardless of any other factors.

Answer (score 7):

> Merge the three "belongs on another site" off-topic sub-reasons into one.

No, those are split out for a good reason. You often want to direct someone to the correct site *without* migrating their question. You might need to do this to avoid creating a duplicate, or just to let someone know the correct site without migrating a low-quality question. Please leave this as-is.

> Retain "unclear". However, merge "request for debugging with no MVCE" into it.

No, those are two distinct reasons. One is for when it is unclear what someone is asking and the other is for when it is clear, but the question can't be answered without some missing details. Please leave as-is.

> Retain "opinion-based". But emphasize the "almost entirely" part.

Seems reasonable enough.

> Introduce a new "trivial" reason.

No, that close reason was being abused, and "trivial" is relative. A question that's trivial to an experienced programmer can be a real stumper to a newbie. There are new languages and technologies coming out all the time, and answers to introductory-level questions should be found on Stack Overflow. Please don't reintroduce this close reason.

> Remove "too broad". This is is a magnet for people looking for any old reason to close something, and also can result in interesting questions with potentially interesting answers being closed.

Yes, it can be abused, but a lot of questions really are too broad. If a question takes the form "I have this assignment and I don't even know where to begin..." or "What are all the things I need to know about security in 2017?" then **too broad** is just the right close reason. Please leave this one too.

> Remove "recommend or find an off-site resource"

There's already a site where people can ask for [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), including libraries for development use, so that's covered. As for other kinds of off-site resources, Google and Amazon will do a far better job of providing recommendations and staying up-to-date than we can. Please leave this one as-is.